# How to prevent Libgdx from Drawing Multiple Objects

Tags: java, function, libgdx, game-engine

SO, i have a function that draws objects to the screen and whenever left mouse button is pressed this function is being called. The problem is since computer works really fast the program thinks that i'm keeping pressing the left mouse button for 0.5 second and the function is being called several times. How can i prevent it from happenning ?

Thanks in advance.

Function:

```
public void drawAll(){
batch.begin();
for( int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
if( Assets.draws[i].draw == true ){ batch.draw( Assets.draws[i].sprite, Assets.draws[i].x, Assets.draws[i].y); }
}
batch.end();
}

public void pressedLeft(){
float x = Gdx.input.getX();
float y = Gdx.input.getY();
boolean contin = true;
for( int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
if( contin == true && Assets.draws[i].draw == false ){ Assets.draws[i].draw = true; contin = false; Assets.draws[i].x = x; Assets.draws[i].y = y; }

   } 
}

@Override
public void render(){
.
.
.
drawAll();

if( Gdx.input.isButtonPressed( Input.Buttons.LEFT ) ){ pressedLeft(); }

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Edited. Is it okay now ?

Comment: Better. You have to remember the pressed state, and only react to the first time when pressed changes from false to true. It's possible that libgdx even contains functionality for this where a function is only triggered when a key is pressed or released, not while it is held down.

Comment: Finally solved the problem. I created a new class that implements InputProcessor and that class had a function called touchUp so i was abled to make it work. Thanks for helping out. Will be more cautious next time i ask a question.